# Rails 4.2 Instance Variable Mutability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

Are instance variables in controllers available to all instances of that controller ? Is it possible that they get overridden in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: instance variables are available to only a specific instance of a controller.